# How to route on multiple components in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I have a messaging project in angular 2.
[image: angular 2 routing image]

**Routing Conditions:**

```
1) path: /login , component: LoginComponent
2) path: /inbox , component: InboxMessageComponent
3) path:/inbox/all , "Load InboxMessageListComponent in Right side Box Only",
4) path:/inbox/13 , "Load InboxMessageDetailComponent in Right side Box Only"
```

So I created two routing module named app-routing.module.ts and inbox-routing.module.ts.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
            { path: 'inbox', component: InboxMessageComponent },
            { path: '', component: InboxMessageComponent },
            { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
        ])
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

**inbox-routing.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild([
            {path: '/inbox/list',component: InboxMessageListComponent},
            {path: '/inbox/detail/:id',component: InboxMessageDetailComponent}
        ])
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

**app.component.ts**

```
template : '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'<!--This route-outlet will load "LoginComponent/InboxComponent" depending upon the routing. -->
```

**inbox-message.component.ts**

```
template:`
<sidebar-component></sidebar-component>
<router-outlet></router-outlet> <!-- This will load InboxMessageListComponent or InboxMessageDetailComponent -->
`
```

But the problem is only one  is working at a time. The second one is skipping.

How to Route this kind of project ?

Comment: I have the same issue, do you have any progress ?

Comment: This tutorial points out your problem I guess. https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/child_routes.html

Answer (score 7):

You have to declare one main path and childer paths for example:

```
import {NgModule}             from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {AddProject} from './add-project.component';
import {ViewProject} from './view-project.component';
import {Project} from './charity-project.component';
import {ProjectList} from './charity-project-list.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'project', component: Project,
        children: [
            { path: '', component: ProjectList },
            { path: 'add', component: AddProject },
            { path: 'view/:id', component: ViewProject },
            { path: 'edit/:id', component: AddProject }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class ProjectRoutes { }
```

In children path you have to declare your

```
3) path:/inbox/all , "Load InboxMessageListComponent in Left side Box Only",
4) path:/inbox/13 , "Load InboxMessageDetailComponent in Right side Box Only"
```

Comment: ok, but in my case , I have two routers in two different components named "app.component.ts","inbox-message.component.ts" . Will both the routers work according to route ?

Comment: I cant share it its private sorry, but you can use them both, use them separate and will be ok I think.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `inbox` is a module of the `app` application. In this case you should also import the `inbox` module in module `app` as follow:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
            { path: 'inbox', component: InboxMessageComponent },
            { path: '', component: InboxMessageComponent },
            { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
        ]),
        MyInboxModule
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

See also the link Routing and Natigation in Angular2: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Hope this helps.